# (Java) Trying to read a txt file and count the number of occurrences for each word

Tags: java, counter, cpu-word

I am supposed to write a program that reads a file called mobydick.txt. The file contains the entire text of Moby Dick the book. [The mobydick.txt file looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DkQgl.png)

I have to read the file, display every unique word in the file and then display the number of occurrences of each unique word.

The output should look like:

WORD           Number

the                      43

whale                  12

boat                     93

This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        //Create input stream & scanner
        FileInputStream fin = new FileInputStream("mobydick.txt");
        Scanner fileInput = new Scanner(fin);
        
        //Create Arraylist
        ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
        ArrayList<Integer> count = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        
        //Read through file and find the words
        while(fileInput.hasNext()) 
        {
            //Get next word
            String nextWord = fileInput.next();
            //Determine if the word is in the arraylist
            if(words.contains(nextWord))
            {
                int index = words.indexOf(nextWord);
                count.set(index, count.get(index) + 1);
            }
            else
            {
                words.add(nextWord);
                count.add(1);
            }
            
        }
        //close
        fileInput.close();
        fin.close();
        System.out.println("WORDS COUNT");
        //Print out the results
        for(int i = 0; i < words.size(); i++)
        {
            System.out.print(words.get(i) + "      " + count.get(i) + "\n");
        }
       
    }
}
```

However, when I run this code I get a strange looking [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dTB5O.png).

It's strange because if I run the same code for a smaller and simpler text file like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X7MDX.png), the output looks [exactly like I want it to](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gjuZc.png).

What am I doing wrong with the mobydick.txt?

Comment: Use HashMap<String, Integer>

Comment: What IDE do your use? I think that matters. I think the scanner is not reading UTF-8 stuff(BTW: You had Top, mid, jug, and bot... But no sup?)

Comment: Please don't only post results/data/code as pictures.  Looks like a character encoding problem on your input file.

Answer (score 2):

Just look at the text input file. It contains, for example, `ago-never`. Computer tools for programmers tend to be *extremely* stupid, because us programmers need them to be extremely simple. Scanner splits on whitespace. Period. `-` is not whitespace. Scanner is dutifully giving you `ago-never` as a single token. If the book contains `Cosmic said: "Sheesh, this coding stuff is hard, man!".`, then these are the tokens that scanner is going to give you:

```
Cosmic
said:
"Sheesh,
this
coding
stuff
is
hard,
man!".
```

Which is obviously not what you wanted. You wanted for example `man`. Not `man!".`.

A second issue is that text files are files, and therefore, bag-o-bytes. bytes aren't characters. So, when you turn your file into a scanner, you're implicitly asking the computer to take a wild stab at how to do that, and wild stab it will: It will use 'platform default encoding', which is java-ese for 'never what you want'. There is no easy answer here. Somebody needs to investigate or tell you what the encoding is. It's probably UTF-8. In which case, you gotta tell java about that:

```
new Scanner(fin, "UTF-8")
```

you didn't, so java picked 'platform default encoding', which is some arbitrary and generally wrong choice, and thus something like 'Haägen Dasz' messes up - only the most basic characters tend to survive conversion with the wrong charset encoding.

As to how to solve that first problem, possibly all you really need is to tell scanner that you want the 'thing that is between tokens' to be 'any amount of non-letters'. The delimiter is a regexp which is presumably a concept you haven't been taught yet; it's quite complicated. The regexp `\W+` represents the notion of: "1 or more 'non-word' characters", and that as separator would mean that the sequence of exclamation point, quote, dot, newline - all disappear as merely the thing that separates tokens. - is also not a letter, so, `ago-never` in the input file would then give you two tokens: ago, and never.

You should still lowercase the inputs, scanners cannot do this for you.

To set the delimiter:

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\\W+"); // double backslash. That's not a typo.
```

EDIT: This answer used `[^a-zA-Z]+` before, but as @VGR pointed out in a comment, `\\W+` is easier to understand; it's probably more idiomatic in general.

Comment: A pattern of `"\\W+"` might be easier for someone new to regex to understand.

Comment: @VGR yeah, you're probably right. I'll update the answer